# Add text below the image in staggered gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview, staggered-gridview

I am implementing staggered gridview in one of my app. I am following this tutorial (http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/). but what i want is, adding the text below the image. So can you please tell me how to accomplish this..? I've googled around but cant able to find the right answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add text after grid item image in layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Steps:

1. Download given source code.
2. Include TextView inside `row_grid_item.xml` which is Step-3 given in tutorial.
3. Do operations on any views inside getView() method of custom adapter. Even you can include any views inside custom row layout file and do operations onto it.

(BTW, thanks for referring my article, I am glad!)

Answer (score 1):

```
  private List<ItemObjects> getListItemData(){
    List<ItemObjects> listViewItems = new ArrayList<ItemObjects>();
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Alkane", R.drawable.one));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ethane", R.drawable.two));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Alkyne", R.drawable.three));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Benzene", R.drawable.four));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Amide", R.drawable.one));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Amino Acid", R.drawable.two));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Phenol", R.drawable.three));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Carbonxylic", R.drawable.four));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Nitril", R.drawable.one));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ether", R.drawable.two));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Ester", R.drawable.three));
    listViewItems.add(new ItemObjects("Alcohol", R.drawable.four));

    return listViewItems;
}
```

try this http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/